# SQL - find entry which matches the current date

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, date, sqlalchemy

Following Table (let's name it **validity_period**):

```
-------------------------------
id | valid_from  | valid_until
-------------------------------
1    2012-11-12    2012-12-02
2    2012-12-03    NULL
3    2012-12-15    2012-12-21
```

(**valid_from**   is not nullable; **valid_until** is nullable, but don't have to be null)

Now I want to find out which entry is valid today (2012-12-19). From the logical sight of view it has to be entry 3, because the entries can overlap each other but only one entry is valid on one day. (On 2012-12-22 it has to be entry 2 which is valid.)
Note that all entries can have a **valid_until**, but there can't be more than one entry where **valid_until** is NULL.

How would I perform this in a SQL-Query? (If possible in SQLAlchemy, but I also can translate it myself from raw SQL)

(I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1)

EDIT: Here my final resolution. Thanks to all contributors!

```
SELECT * 
    FROM validity_period 
    WHERE valid_from <= CURRENT_DATE AND 
          valid_until >= CURRENT_DATE
UNION
SELECT * 
    FROM validity_period 
    WHERE valid_from <= CURRENT_DATE AND 
          valid_until IS NULL
ORDER BY valid_from DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: *Why* do you pick id 3 over id 2?

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter: Because id 3 'overrides' the validity of id 2 for the time from 2012-12-15 to 2012-12-21. After that period id 2 is valid again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    validity_period
WHERE   valid_from <= current_date
        AND valid_to >=current_date    
UNION 

--Gets the last instance where valid_until is null
SELECT * 
FROM validity_period 
WHERE   valid_from <= current_date
        AND valid_to IS NULL
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Simply remove the DESC if you want the first rather than the last null field

Comment: This is so close to what I think he wants that it is not worth providing another answer.  I think he wants that maximum `valid_from` as the one row that is returned.  This just requires changing the `order by` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a WINDOW function (such as lag or lead) to refer to the previous/next record, and cap the "open" intervals:

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path=tmp;

CREATE TABLE daterange
        ( id INTEGER NOT NULL
        , valid_from  DATE NOT NULL
        , valid_until DATE
        );
INSERT INTO daterange (id, valid_from, valid_until) VALUES
 (1, '2012-11-12', '2012-12-02' )
,(2, '2012-12-03', NULL)
,(3, '2012-12-15', '2012-12-21' )
,(4, '2012-12-22', NULL )
        ;

-- The CTE is for convenience; could be a subquery or view
WITH magic AS (
        SELECT dr.id
        , dr.valid_from
        , COALESCE(dr.valid_until , lead(valid_from) OVER ww) AS valid_until
        FROM daterange dr
        WINDOW ww AS (ORDER BY dr.valid_from )
        )
SELECT *
FROM magic ma
WHERE now() BETWEEN ma.valid_from AND ma.valid_until
        ;
```

Comment: I really like your resolution but @twoleggedhorse 's also works for me and it's less complex (and it's database independent, mention I'm working with SQLAlchemy). But you got a +1 from me!

Answer (score 0):

The valid_until is logically redundant in the data you give as an example, and you might get a faster result with this logic if an index on valid_from is present and PostgreSQL will perform a descending index scan:

```
select   *
from     validity_period
where    valid_from <= current_date
order by valid_from desc
limit    1
```

Check the explain plan to see if it is an improvement on larger data sets.

Edit: If there can be a situation where the "last" record has a valid until date prior to today, where no rows are to be returned, try:

```
select   most_recent_record.*
from     (
         select   *
         from     validity_period
         where    valid_from <= current_date
         order by valid_from desc
         limit    1) most_recent_record
where    coalesce(most_recent_record.valid_until,current_date) <= current_date
```

That last predicate might read better as:

```
where    not (most_recent_record.valid_until > current_date)
```

Comment: Doesn't work. There has not be a entry where valid_until is NULL. [For example](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/24705455/sql.jpg)

Comment: So you can have a situation where the "last" record has a valid until date prior to today, and then you want no rows to be returned?

Comment: Added another version for that.

Answer (score 0):

You question is not very clear. Can there be more than one matches with non-null `valid_until`? Which to pick? What do you want to return? One column? Several? All?

Anyhow, what you posted as solution can be simplified to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   validity_period 
WHERE  valid_from  <= now()::date
AND   (valid_until >= now()::date OR valid_until IS NULL) -- parenthesis needed!
ORDER  BY valid_from DESC 
LIMIT  1;
```